# Import from excel to sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, import

I have records in excel spreadsheet. Is there a way to create a view and insert the excel data into it(I don't want to create a table for this) ? Thank you

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible without creating table.  Real question is why you don't want to create a table?  Do you need the view to be in perfect sync with the Excel data?

Comment: A view does not exist without a table.  That's like asking how to make a window without making a hole in the wall.

Comment: some users have access only to views not to tables. It is just one time dump from excel to view. Is there any other way I could do it(create temptable etc.,)

Comment: Create a read only excel file on a network drive.

Comment: Create a table and then create a dumb view of that table for the users with view only access.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the Excel data using SQL Server OPENROWSET but I can't remember if you can define a view with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

try to Copy the entire data . then edit youre table paste the data in youre table